# How to cast set in list into list in python?

Tags: python, casting

I want to cast set in list to list like below.

```
before: [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
after: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

I need the as simple code as possible.

Comment: Why? Those are mostly equivalent anyway. (And there's no such thing as casting in Python.)

Comment: Those aren't sets, they're tuples. `after = [list(inner) for inner in before]`.

Comment: I am confused about that a little. thank you! Right. they are tuples.

Comment: BTW, tuples are more efficient than lists. You should probably leave them as tuples, unless you need to mutate them.

Comment: @이춘경: If either of the proposed answers was helpful to you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
>>> list(map(list, x))
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

### Explanation

`map(list, x)` takes an iterable `x` and applies function `list` to each element of this iterable. Thus the tuple `(1, 1, 1)` becomes the list `[1, 1, 1]`, `(1, 1, 0)` becomes `[1, 1, 0]` and `(1, 0, 1)` becomes `[1, 0, 1]`.

These lists are then stored in a `map` object (assuming Python 3.x). A `map` object is an iterator, which can be converted to a list by calling `list` on it, as shown above. Often, though, you don't need to make this explicit conversion because iterator allows you to traverse the elements directly:

```
>>> for elem in map(list, x):
...     print(elem)
...
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define "before" as a variable called "array". Then we take the for-loop of the "array" while casting each element to a list.

```
array = [(1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1)]
casted_array = []
for tuples in array:
    casted_array.append(list(tuples))
```

There are slightly easier ways to do this, but they are harder to understand. Explanation: You define the list [(1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1)] as a variable and then define a "dummy" variable called "casted_array". You then loop through the items in the "array" variable while saving them to the "tuples" iteration variable. Every time the iteration cycle loops, the sets/tuples are converted into lists and then added on to the "casted_array" variable. The casted set/tuple is now stored in the "casted_array" variable.