# How to remove intersection between two lists?

Tags: python

I have two variables like below

```
k1 = [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
k2 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

I want to remove [0, 1, 1] in each list.
So the results would be like below.

```
k1 = [[0, 0, 0]]
k2 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: how long do you expect the lists to be? You can just do `k1 = [sub for sub in k1 if sub not in k2]` and then the same for `k2` if they are not that big.

Comment: This would be easier if `k1` and `k2` were sets of tuples. That's another benefit of tuples I didn't mention [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53442777/how-to-cast-set-in-list-into-list-in-python#comment93759113_53442777).

Comment: Can a list contain duplicates? If so, should all duplicates be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Search the intersection and filter with a comprehension:

```
>>> k2 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
>>> k1 = [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> intersection = [x for x in k2 if x in k1]
>>> intersection
[[0, 1, 1]]
>>> k2 = [x for x in k2 if x not in intersection]
>>> k2
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
>>> k1 = [x for x in k1 if x not in intersection]
>>> k1
[[0, 0, 0]]
```